# Android/iOS app seems to be using Facebook Single Sign-on when I don't want it to

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Details of our app:

- Unity 5.6.5
- Facebook SDK for Unity
- Single Sign-On is not enabled for
  Android or iOS.

With Facebook app installed on device and signed in, the player can only sign in to our app with the same Facebook account that is signed into the Facebook app.  Explicitly signing out of Facebook from our app, and attempting to sign back in results in automatically signing in to the same account again.  This is the SSO behaviour isn't it?

Without the Facebook app installed, signing out and signing in again results in the sign-in dialog appearing, so a different account can be signed into.  This is the behaviour we want regardless of whether or not the Facebook app is installed.

Is this a bug in the Facebook sign in process?  Am I misunderstanding SSO?  How can we get the behaviour that we want?

Thanks.

Colin

Comment: You are only allowed to have one Facebook account. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Are you saying that it is impossible to sign in to the Facebook app with one account, and sign in to Facebook within another app with another account?

Comment: I'm saying that you are only allowed to have one Facebook account. So what is your usecase when you need to login using 2 different accounts?

Comment: Passing your device (on which you are signed in to the Facebook app) to a friend so he can play a game and sign into Facebook inside that game.

Comment: @WizKid can you offer any more help with this issue?